# What does 'add 0x804a460(,%ecx,4),%edx' do?

Tags: assembly, x86

I need help interpreting this line of code:

```
   0x08048e26 <+43>:    add    0x804a460(,%ecx,4),%edx
```

I'm not sure what this means exactly.  I am interpreting it as `%edx = 4*%ecx + 0x804a460`. This doesn't seem to be correct though, as `%edx` never contains the values I expect it to after running the instruction.

Comment: It's an `add`, not a `mov`, so that would be `%edx += [4*%ecx + 0x804a460]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent in C is

```
edx += *((int*)0x804a460 + ecx)
```

Looks like it is indexing into a static table to get the value of an entry, then adding that value to edx.